# How to create c++ equivalent of Objective-C completion block as param

Tags: c++, objective-c

Our iOS app depends on a c++ library. I'm new to c++, and I'm looking for the c++ equivalent of this:

Definition:

```
- (void)mySetter:(Thing)thing completion:(void (^)(BOOL))completion;
```

Use:

```
[self mySetter:thing completion:^(BOOL success) {
    // do something if successful
}]
```

I know this is a dumb question that's probably been answered, but all the answers I've come across are still pretty confusing for a c++ noob.

Happy to delete, but more happy to give out upvotes and check marks :)

Comment: Recommend adding some of the other answers you've found for this to the question and tell us what you found confusing. It'll be easier and better for the site to clean up a good, existing answer than add a new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++ you would usually use [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) for this, which is a class template that can hold any kind of callable function/object including a [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) (caveat: as long as it's copyable):

```cpp
void mySetter(Thing thing, std::function<void(bool)> completion) {
  // ...
  completion(true);
}

mySetter(thing, [](bool success) {
  // ...
});
```

Note that **in Objective-C++** (.mm files) you can generally mix C++ and Obj-C types freely, so you could for example pass a block as a parameter to a C++ function — you just need to be aware of the proper [block pointer syntax](http://goshdarnblocksyntax.com/).

```c
void mySetter(Thing thing, void (^completion)(BOOL)) {
  // ...
  completion(YES);
}

mySetter(thing, ^(BOOL success) {
  // ...
});
```

Comment: Oh! I see! Yep, that'll do it! Thanks!